# CrystalReportViewer & CrystalReportDocument missing from ToolBox in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2015 IDE for development & developing windowsforms and using C# language but Crystal Report Viewer missing from ToolBox in Visual Studio 2015.

I googled it and found solution-->
Open Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features, and select the entry for your version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. In our case, it was Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
Click the "Change" button on the top bar above the program list.
After the splash screen, a window will open. Press the "Modify" button.
Select Windows and Web Development > Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, and check the box next to it.
Press the "Update" button on the lower-right hand side of the window.
Once the installation is complete, open your version of Visual Studio. After the new .dll files are loaded, Reporting functionality should be reimplemented, and you should be able to access all related forms, controls, and objects.

It solved the problem to some extent but still missing CrystalReportViewer & CrytalReportDocument from ToolBox in Visual Studio.

The image is given below after updating the Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
  [image]

Comment: Do you already have the dlls? or the project somewhere? If you do, you might want to right click the toolbox and then Choose Items...-> Browse -> and select the dll of the framework you using. Then it will show in your toolbox.

Comment: there are only two dlls of Reporting in the directory of visual studio into C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

Comment: Did you try to import them to the toolbox?

Comment: they are already import but I import it again and still the result is same

Comment: Then these DLLs are just part of the API. What you need to look for, the missing dll that contains the CrystalReportViewer **Control**. Then once you import it into the toolbox, you'll be able to drag and drop to the form. You might want to check this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalReports.VisualStudio2015.x64/2.0.0

Comment: @GiladReich Thanks a lot. The problem has solved